# Qgis2web large dataset//WMS

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I have 2 issues:

- With **Qgis2web** I can't export a heavy vector layer either as .shp or WMS.
- I also can't make it display, the list of different values of the same attribute in the pop-up menu.

Comment: How big is your dataset? What format is your vector data?

Comment: Qgis2web exports all vector layers to geojson.  It does not export to WMS.  Are you able to export your layer in Qgis to geojson?  What language are your attributes?  Are they any special characters?

Comment: Note that large datasets will take a long time to load when the website is loaded. You might think of a Mapserver/Geoserver or cloud solution that delivers only the data that is actually requested.

Comment: @nmtoken - its actually only 25.000 vector polygons

Comment: @GreyHippo :: yes i'm able to export as geojson. Im not sure of the language. No special characters, only numbers in fact

Comment: @AndreJ - its not because i am impatient - they dont show ever.

Comment: @GreyHippo Btw. When I try to export with the .shp layer Qgis2web exports NONE of the other layers either. When I try to export the same layers that i have loaded as WMS the other layers function in the export and the legend for the WMS layer is shown, but not the actual data...

Comment: I would try using q2w with only one layer and using a simple symbology and then try and export.  Keep in mind that 25,000 is large and it may take some time.

Comment: @GreyHippo - you were right. It worked with a simple symbology - though the point is kind of lost then.

Comment: Now we know q2w works with your data so keep tweeking your project to see exactly what steps cause error in q2w.  By tweeking I mean add a graduated class style to your layer then try q2w again.  Rinse and repeat...

Comment: If you are able, upload a copy of your data and qgis project file.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to make Qgis2web not handle the dataset (25.000 polygons) with complex symbology  resultning in that NO layers were shown.

Using a simple symbology however it worked.

(Reducing from 14 graduated classes to 1)